# Can multiple outlets be directly attached to a single breaker?

Tags: electrical

Are either of these ok:

a) Two NEMA-5-20 outlets, each has a run of #12 wire, that runs all the way to a single breaker, which then clamps 2 black #12 wires.

b) Two NEMA-14-50 outlets, each has a run of #6 wire, that runs all the way to the breaker which clamps on two red leads and two black leads.

Comment: What is plugged into the two NEMA 14-50s?

Comment: Electric car chargers.

Comment: How far apart are the two NEMA 14-50 outlets? Is replacing the home runs for them an option?

Comment: Also, what make/series are the breakers in question? (If you don't know, add a photo to your question and we can help you ID them :)  Furthermore, do you have spare spaces in your panel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> a) Two NEMA-5-20 outlets, each has a run of #12 wire, that runs all the way to a single breaker, which then clamps 2 black #12 wires.

It depends on the specifications of the breaker. If it allows 2 wires then OK. If not, just connect the two wires to a third wire (pigtail) and connect that wire to the breaker.

> b) Two NEMA-14-50 outlets, each has a run of #6 wire, that runs all the way to the breaker which clamps on two red leads and two black leads.

**No**. See [Wire two 14-50 outlets to 50 amp breaker](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/93934/wire-two-14-50-outlets-to-50-amp-breaker)

Comment: How do I know if the breaker specs allow 2 wires?

Comment: @samsmith -- it will say on the breaker's label what wire sizes and how many wires are allowed in the breaker's lug

Comment: The additional question is whether AFCI is required for the 20 amp circuit. If so, pigtails or AFCI receptacles are the only option - AFCI or GFCI breakers can't accept more than one set of wires (hot and neutral).

Answer (score 1):

### You can't have 2 outlets on a 50A branch circuit in a house for non-cooking appliances

NEC 210.23(C) prohibits putting 2 outlets on a 50A branch circuit in a house unless you are supplying cooking appliances *only*, which is not the case for you:

> **(C) 40- and 50-Ampere Branch Circuits.** A 40- or 50-ampere
>   branch circuit shall be permitted to supply cooking appliances
>   that are fastened in place in any occupancy. In other than
>   dwelling units, such circuits shall be permitted to supply fixed
>   lighting units with heavy-duty lampholders, infrared heating
>   units, or other utilization equipment.

### Not only can you not have 2 outlets on 1 50A branch circuit in a house, but you can't put 2 electric car chargers on 1 circuit *anywhere*

Even if this wasn't in a house, your situation with the 50A outlets is still no good, because of NEC 625.40:

> **625.40 Electric Vehicle Branch Circuit.** Each outlet installed
>   for the purpose of charging electric vehicles shall be supplied
>   by an individual branch circuit. Each circuit shall have no other
>   outlets.

Comment: And by "outlet" they mean "point of use", not "receptacle".  So hardwiring to bypass the receptacle buys you nothing.

Comment: Thanks. I think I'll hardwire two tesla wall chargers, to discrete breakers, and they will smartly do the right thing re overall load